# ERROR: make: *** No rule to make target `main.c', needed by `main.o'. Stop

Tags: c, linux, makefile

```
CC= gcc

CFLAGS= -D__XMLSEC_FUNCTION__=__FUNCTION__ -DXMLSEC_NO_XSLT=1 \
  -DXMLSEC_NO_XKMS=1 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DXMLSEC_CRYPTO_DYNAMIC_LOADING=1 \
  -DXMLSEC_CRYPTO=\"openssl\" -DUNIX_SOCKETS -DXML_SECURITY -DDEBUG \
  -I/usr/local/include/xmlsec1 -lxmlsec1 

LDFLAGS= -lcrypto -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/include/xmlsec1 \
  -lxmlsec1 -lprotobuf-c

default: shr
#pb stands for protobuf file

shr:    main.o  file2.o file3.pb-c.o
            $(CC)   $(CFLAGS)   -o shr main.o   file2.o file3.pb-c.o

main.o: main.c  header.hfile2.h file3.h
                $(CC)   $(CFLAGS)   -c main.c

file2.o:    file2.c file2.h
                $(CC)   $(CFLAGS)   -c axisuid_auth.c

file3.pb-c.o:   file3.pb-c.c    file3.h
                $(CC)   $(CFLAGS)   -c file3.c

clean:
        $(RM)   shr *.o *~
```

Comment: You have no file named `main.c` in the directory you're working in.

Comment: all .c & .h files are in src folder.

Comment: `make` does not get anything wrong. If it complains about a missing file, then **there is a file missing.**

Comment: Use `remake -x` to debug your `Makefile`. I suspect you are not running `make` in the `src` *directory*. Or mention `src/main.c` etc... (with the `src/` directory explicitly given) in the `Makefile`

Comment: s/there is a file missing/there isn't a file where you told `make` it is/

Comment: Check that you are using [TABS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)#Rules) correctly, rather than whitespace.

Comment: Also, add `-Wall` to your `CFLAGS`. Asking all warnings to your compiler is always helpful.

Comment: This is a stupidly agressive use of downvoting against a new user. Obviously there's a `main.c` and it's not being picked up for whatever reason. Don't just throw the error message back at the guy.

Comment: after debugging using remake : default file does not exist

Comment: take time to read again the GNU make documentation http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html ; there is something basic about `make` that you did not understand, hence you are not giving enough relevant information (what it your source tree structure? from which directory are you running `make`, etc...) for us to help you.

Comment: @BrettHale: I tend to disagree with your opinion against down-voting. The question is really badly formulated, and don't give enough clues for any `make` expert to answer. (This is why I downvoted the question, but I did try to provide help thru comments).

Answer (score 4):

As you said, all the .c and .h files are in **src folder**. So in that case in your Makefile you should specify it as **src/main.c**

Comment: same for allheaders and other c files??

Comment: src/header.h src /file2.c

Comment: after debugging using remak command default & shr file do not exist...

Comment: Yes, the `Makefile` should explicitly mention each `src/*.c` `src/*.h` file. Alternatively, consider putting the `Makefile` into `src/` and running `make` from inside `src/` directory.